# Unity - how can I conditionally create a child scope?

Tags: c#, unity-container

If I have:

```
container.RegisterType<ICalculationBuilder, CalculationBuilder>();
```

I know I will get a new instance each time I resolve an ICalculationBuilder.

I know that If do:

```
var childContainer = container.CreateChildContainer();

childContainer.RegisterType<ICalculationBuilder, CalculationBuilder>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

Then I will get the same instance each time I resolve an ICalculationBuilder within that child scope.

But given:

```
class CalculationBuilder
{
  CalculationBuilder(int year)
  {
  }
}
```

How can I get a different instance of a CalculationBuilder for each year? So If I do:

```
var builder1 = childContainer.Resolve(typeof(ICalculationBuilder), new DependencyOverride<int>(2017));

var builder2 = childContainer.Resolve(typeof(ICalculationBuilder), new DependencyOverride<int>(2017));

var builder3 = childContainer.Resolve(typeof(ICalculationBuilder), new DependencyOverride<int>(2018));
```

Then

```
Assert.Same(builder1, builder2) would be true
```

and

```
Assert.NotSame(builder2, builder3) would be false
```

Comment: Well you don't, if the year is important for the calculation itself, it should be rather part of the method you are calling to create whatever you are building

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately that's not possible. A calculation may not change from year to year and there again, it might. The calculation builder may build calculationA which may in turn call the calculation builder to build calculationB. The year is passed into the builder because there may be a year specific version of calculationB -> calculationB2017.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can create some sort of factory to manage you objects:

```
class CalculationFactory : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, CalculationBuilder> cache = new Dictionary<int, CalculationBuilder>();
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    public ICalculationBuilder Get(int year)
    {
        if (!cache.ContainsKey(year))
        {
            cache[year] = container.Resolve(typeof(ICalculationBuilder), new DependencyOverride<int>(year));
        }

        return cache[year];
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        cache.Clear();
    }
}
```

And create objects via this class only. It will cache insatnces for every year.

Comment: @Adam can you accept this answer, or you need more information?